# what does interpolation of non-equal dimension means in Python?

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, interpolation, psychopy

I am looking at source code of Psychopy program, and I encountered the below line.

```
interpolateCones = scipy.interpolate.interp1d(wavelength_5nm, cones_SmithPokorny)
```

in which `wavelength_5nm` is a (1,81) vector and `cones_SmithPokorny` dimension is (3,81) and both of them contain predefined numbers.

I really cannot understand the meaning of interpolating with input parameters of non-equal dimensions. shouldn't `cones_SmithPokorny` be (1,81) too? why there is no error when I run the code?

Comment: Sounds like a case of [numpy broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html): the first dimension of `wavelength_5nm`, which is 1, will repeated following the first dimension of `cones_SmithPokorny`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`interp1d` has default value `axis=-1`, so the 1D interpolation is over the last axis.
I.e., there are 81 x-coordinates, and for each x-coordinate there are 3 y-values.
So it's not interpolating across unequal dimensions.